# Ajax Request are not working with Pac4j / Shiro?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, shiro, pac4j

After switch from FormAuthentication via Shiro, I switched to Pac4, Shiro with Keycloak.

I recognized in my JSF pages the Ajax requests are not working anymore, like:

```
<h:form>
        <p:outputPanel deferred="true" loaded="#{not empty myBean.lazyModel}">

                <p:ajax event="load" listener="#{myBean.init()}" />
                .....
```

myBean.init() is never called?

Edit:
I´ve updated the shiro.ini with this line, than it´s working. But I don´t think this is the correct approach!

```
oidcSecurityFilter.authorizers = none
```

Definition of: oidcSecurityFilter

```
oidcSecurityFilter = org.pac4j.jee.filter.SecurityFilter
```

If I debug in the org.pac4j.jee.filter.SecurityFilter I got for:

```
final SecurityLogic bestLogic = #DefaultSecurityLogic# | clientFinder: org.pac4j.core.client.finder.DefaultSecurityClientFinder@8beb950 | authorizationChecker: org.pac4j.core.authorization.checker.DefaultAuthorizationChecker@707a8365 | matchingChecker: org.pac4j.core.matching.checker.DefaultMatchingChecker@55ba1e41 | errorUrl: null | savedRequestHandler: org.pac4j.core.engine.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequestHandler@6d270088 |
```

I´m not authenticated due this line in 138:
org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic

```
if (isNotEmpty(profiles)) {
                    LOGGER.debug("authorizers: {}", authorizers);
                    if (authorizationChecker.isAuthorized(context, sessionStore, profiles,                                                     authorizers, config.getAuthorizers(), currentClients)) {
```

It´s using the org.pac4j.core.authorization.checker.DefaultAuthorizationChecker

If I not define this extra line  in shiro.ini, the authorizers are:

```
[#CsrfAuthorizer# | parameterName: pac4jCsrfToken | headerName: pac4jCsrfToken | checkAllRequests: false |, #IsAuthenticatedAuthorizer# | redirectionUrl: null |]
```

Is this a bug?
Do I need some further settings in shiro.ini ?

Comment: I´m pretty sure it´s a Pac4j topic. There needs some more settings from your side (Keycloak etc.) to reproduce it.

Comment: (with working link) Please provide a [mcve]. A great project to start from would be github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: You can add anything you like to the project. As long as it is relevant to your issue.

Comment: Keycloak config is outside the project

Comment: That does not change anything from the fact that a [mcve] is needed in order to say anything about your problem.

Comment: Here my producer: https://file.io/C3UbWtAfnwqN
init() in TestBeanController is never called from test.xhtml page
Start with: 
Maven: package jetty:run